# Flot doesn't show chart in localhost

Tags: php, flot

I am trying to plot a chart with some data queried from mysql with Flot. 
Because I have never used Flot before, I start with trying to reproduce the examples provided by Flot, for example this one: 
http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/index.html

I downloaded the above html page (and renamed it with test.html) in the local folder of my website, as well as all the necessary javascript sources and CSS, and put them in the same folder, and corrected the paths in the html page so that the js codes and css can be found.

The problem is, the chart works perfectly if I open this html file with its absolute path: file:///data/www/test_website/test.html, but it doesn't work if I open it with 127.0.0.2/test.html.

Could anyone help? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

There is no error when I tried the absolute path. But when I tried with 127.0.0.2/test.html, it has the following errors:

```
jquery.canvaswrapper.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined

appContent.js:54 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you share your modified source. Also I don't see  a script called appContent.js in the example you linked.

Comment: Check if you load all JavaScript files with relative links. You can't load a script with `file:///...` when you opened the page with `http://localhost/...`.